# Upgrading from Bootstrap 3.3.7 to 4.x.x breaks the layout

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

Just tried to upgrade jquery and boostrap of my ASP.net Core 2.2 app to the most recent versions. While I did not experience any issues with jquery (from 2.x to 3.4.1), that does not count for Bootstrap. I could update the bootstrap.js from 3.3.7 to 4.3.1 without issues but as soon as I cross the 3.3.7 -> 4.0.0 barrier with the .css template of bootstrap, the design of my page is broken. Especially the navbar does not work anymore. Only thing I did was to change from glyphicon to FontsAwesome. Are there any other breaking changes that I have to keep track of?

Here's a snippet of my **_Layout.cshtml**:

```
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-header navbar-fixed-top">
            <!--div class="container" DB: Responsible for not sticking to the left border-->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>            
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    @{Html.RenderPartial("Menu/TopMenu"); }

                </ul>

                <p class="pull-right navbar-text"><span class="far fa-address-card"></span> @User.Identity.Name?.Split("\\")[1]</p>

                <ul>
                    <!--li><a href="?culture=de">Deutsch</a><li>
                    <li><a href="?culture=it">Italiano</a></li-->
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!--/div-->
        </nav>
        <div class="body-content">
            @RenderSection("Heading", required: false) @{ if (Model != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.ErrorMessage)) {
            <h1 class="text-danger text-center">@Model.ErrorMessage</h1> } else if (Model != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.SuccessMessage)) {
            <h1 class="text-success text-center">@Model.SuccessMessage</h1> } } @RenderBody()

            <footer style="position: relative; clear:both;">
                <hr />
                <p>&copy; @Model.CurrentYear - Companyname S.A. / @Html.ActionLink("Changelog", "VersionHistory")</p>
            </footer>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the **TopMenu.cshtml**:

```
<li>
    <a href="#" id="AllgemeinMenuDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown">@Localizer["General"]</a>@*Allgemein*@
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="AllgemeinMenuDropdown">
        <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Parameter" asp-action="ListDealer">@SharedLocalizer["VehicleOverview"]</a></li>
        @*Fahrzeug Übersicht*@ @*Preisschildgenerator*@
    </ul>
</li>

<li>
    <a href="#" id="VerkaufMenuDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown">@SharedLocalizer["Sales"]</a>@*Verkauf*@
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="VerkaufMenuDropdown">
        <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Checklist" asp-action="Index">@SharedLocalizer["Checklist"]</a></li>
        @*Checkliste*@
        <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="StockExplorer" asp-action="Index">@SharedLocalizer["StockExplorer"]</a></li>
        @*Stock Exploer*@ @*@if (User.IsInRole(AdGroups.ALL_PC_PRICE_TAG_GENERATOR)) {
        <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="PriceTag" asp-action="Index">@SharedLocalizer["PriceTagGenerator"]</a></li>
        }*@
        <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="PriceTag" asp-action="Index">@SharedLocalizer["PriceTagGenerator"]</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Sales" asp-action="VisionOrderNumber">@Localizer["VisionOrderNumber"]</a></li>@*VisionOrderNumber*@
<li>
    <a href="#" id="DispoMenuDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown">@SharedLocalizer["Disposition"]</a>@*Disposition*@
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="DispoMenuDropdown">
        <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="GoodWill" asp-action="GoodWillIndex">@SharedLocalizer["GoodWill"]</a></li>
        <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Parameter" asp-action="ListDealer">@SharedLocalizer["OrderConfirmation"]</a></li>@*Auftragsbestätigung*@
        <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="PickUpAndDelivery" asp-action="Index">@SharedLocalizer["OrderCancellation"]</a></li>@*Fahrzeug Stornierung*@
    </ul>
</li>

<li>
    <a href="#" id="SalesAdminMenuDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown">@SharedLocalizer["SalesAdmin"]</a>@*Sales Admin*@
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="SalesAdminMenuDropdown">
        <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Checklist" asp-action="Index">@SharedLocalizer["FileProcessing"]</a></li>
        @*Aktenbearbeitung*@
        <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="StockExplorer" asp-action="Index">@SharedLocalizer["Kennzeichenverwaltung"]</a></li>
        @*Kennzeichenverwaltung*@
        <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Preisschild" asp-action="Index">@SharedLocalizer["PaymentToCustomer"]</a></li>
        @*Zahlung an Kunde*@
    </ul>
</li>

<li>
    <a href="#" id="PDILogistikMenuDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown">@SharedLocalizer["PdiLogistics"]</a>@*PDI / Logistik*@
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="PDILogistikMenuDropdown">
        <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Checklist" asp-action="Index">@SharedLocalizer["PdiPlanning"]</a></li>
        @*PDI-Planung*@
        <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="StockExplorer" asp-action="Index">@SharedLocalizer["DeliveryPlanning"]</a></li>
        @*Auslieferplanung*@
        <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Preisschild" asp-action="Index">@SharedLocalizer["VehicleWorkPlanning"]</a></li>
        @*Planung Arbeiten am Fahrzeug*@
        <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Preisschild" asp-action="Index">@SharedLocalizer["ArrivalPlanning"]</a></li>
        @*Ankunftsplanung*@
        <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Preisschild" asp-action="Index">@SharedLocalizer["WorkshopVehicleOverview"]</a></li>
        @*Übersicht Werkstattfahrzeuge*@
        <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Preisschild" asp-action="Index">@SharedLocalizer["PreparationPlanning"]</a></li>
        @*Aufbereitungsplanung*@
    </ul>
</li>

<li>
    <a href="#" id="AuslieferungMenuDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown">@SharedLocalizer["Delivery"]</a>@*Auslieferung*@
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="AuslieferungMenuDropdown">
        <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Checklist" asp-action="Index">@SharedLocalizer["DeliveryChecklist"]</a></li>
        @*Auslieferung Checkliste*@
        <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Checklist" asp-action="Index">@SharedLocalizer["DeliveryCalendar"]</a></li>
        @*Auslieferung Kalender*@ @*TODO => ?!*@
    </ul>
</li>

@*TODO: Sollte auf Report Server ausgelagert werden.*@
<li>
    <a href="#" id="ReportsMenuDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown">@SharedLocalizer["Reports"]</a>@*Reports*@
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="ReportsMenuDropdown">
        <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Checklist" asp-action="Index">@SharedLocalizer["ReportA"]</a></li>
        @*Report A*@
    </ul>
</li>

<li>
    <a href="#" id="DatenManagementMenuDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown">@SharedLocalizer["DataManagement"]</a>@*Datenverwaltung*@
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="DatenManagementMenuDropdown">
        <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="InternalServices" asp-action="Index">@SharedLocalizer["VehicleWork"]</a></li>
        @*Arbeiten am Fahrzeug*@
        <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Branch" asp-action="Index">@SharedLocalizer["Branches"]</a></li>
        @*???*@
        <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="FinanceTypes" asp-action="Index">@SharedLocalizer["FinanceTypes"]</a></li>
        @*Finanzierungsarten*@
        <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="WarrantyTypes" asp-action="Index">@SharedLocalizer["WarrantyTypes"]</a></li>
        @*Garantieen*@
        <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="PickUpAndDelivery" asp-action="Index">@SharedLocalizer["PickUpAndDeliveryCompanies"]</a></li>
        @*Hol & Bring Firmen*@
    </ul>
</li>

<li>
    <a href="#" id="SucheMenuDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown">@SharedLocalizer["Suche"]</a>@*Suche*@
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="SucheMenuDropdown">
        <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Parameter" asp-action="ListDealer">@SharedLocalizer["AllgemeineSuche"]</a></li>
        @*Allgemeine Suche*@

    </ul>
</li>

<li>
    <environment names="Development, Demo">
        <div style="color: red; text-align: center; font-size:32px; font-weight: bold; border-style: solid;">DEVELOPMENT ENVIRONMENT</div>
    </environment>
</li>
```

Here's what the design looked

before:
https://abload.de/image.php?img=beforeaqku4.png

after:
https://abload.de/image.php?img=aftera2jdh.png

Comment: Don't use external image hosters, upload it on StackExchange/StackOverflow. External hosters can go offline and then the links to the images become invalid and question useless for people who stumble upon it in future

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bootstrap 4 was a huge rewrite. You'll need to read through the documentation [Migrating to v4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/migration/).

There are too many changes to cover here.

Comment: Since the navigation was the main issue named there, maybe you could take over the example for that one so its not a pure external link only answer?

Answer (score 0):

I misunderstood the section where it said that upgrading from Beta 3 to Final v4 would not have any deal breakers. I thought they meant upgrading from v3 to v4 but they ment Beta 3 of version 4. But I will go on using the latest v3 version since there are some major changes as pointed out by Rowan Freeman.

> **Stable changes**
>
> Moving from Beta 3 to our stable v4.0 release, there are no breaking changes, but there are some notable changes.